# meaning of 'zu Viert mehr Platz' in a sentence

Tags: meaning

In this sentense,

> Zuerst wollten wir nur eine größere Wohnung, um zu Viert mehr Platz zu haben.

I would interpret it as

> First, we just wanted a bigger apartment in order to have a fourth room.

But google translator interpreted it as

> First, we just wanted a bigger apartment in order to have four more rooms.

I thought because it's "Viert mehr Platz", it's "fourth added space".
If it were "four more rooms" it would have been "vier mehr Plätze".
Who is correct? me or google translator?
(I'm studying on my own, and sometimes have this kinds of questions..)

Comment: You parse it not correct. It's not "Viert mehr Platz" which is a grammatical unit but "zu viert" and "mehr Platz".

Comment: BTW, I recommend to use [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) instead of Google Translate. DeepL can translate such sentences correctly.

Comment: @tavkomann Wow, thanks. that was a very helpful information.

Comment: "zu viert mehr Platz" = "more room for the four of us".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both your interpretation and the Google translator are wrong in this case.
*Zu Viert* describes that the sentence is about a bunch of four people.

The phrase can be extended to other numerals larger or equal than 2:

> Zu Zweit, zu Dritt, zu Viert, zu Fünft, zu Sechst, ..., zu Achzigst, ...

Other examples:

> Wir sind zu Viert verreist
> We travelled as a group of four people
>
> Heute waren wir nur zu dritt
> Today we were only three

Comment: I didn't know the ordinal number is used in this way in German. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

None of your translations is very accurate, unfortunately. (Google:Chan Kim 0:0)

*zu viert* translates roughly to "the four of us".

So the translation would be along the line of

> First, we just wanted a bigger apartment to have more room for the four of us.
>
> First, we just wanted a bigger apartment to have more room for our [group|family] of four

So, nothing is said about the apartment, but rather the amount of people who want to live in there.

Comment: At first we only wanted a bigger apartment to have more room for four?

Comment: Hi, I chose the other answer because it provided with two examples about how to use the oridnal number this way.  But I liked the 0:0 part :)

Comment: »zu viert translates roughly to "the four of us"«: only if there's a »wir«. It could also as well be »you« or »them« in other contexts.